# Is there a class loading issue with Apache Flink, JDBC and fat jars?

Tags: java, classloader, apache-flink

using Apache Flink 1.8 and trying to run a `RichAsyncFunction`.

And I get `No Suitable Driver Found` error when initializing the Hikari pool inside the `RichAsyncFunction open()`

In the IDE it works great, when submitting to the cluster I get the above error.

I resolved this by putting `Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")`

I'm guessing this is a some sort of class loading issue with how Apache Flink loads the classes and fat jars? As with the "latest" pools and drivers, you don't really have to do this any more. JTDS is a type 3 driver and Hikari seems to usually detect this in regular fat jars that I usually create.

My Gradle dependencies are as such:

```
compile "net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:${jtdsVersion}"
flinkShadowJar "net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:${jtdsVersion}"
```